# How to extract number of data assigned to each Self-Organizing Map (SOM) nodes in R?

Tags: r, count

Does anyone know how to extract count (number of data) assigned to each SOM nodes in R?
Currently I can only plot the number of count for each node using "plot(som.model, type = "count")". I am interesting to know how many data are actually assigned to each nodes.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- plot(som.model, type = "count")
a
```

"a" should contain how many samples are mapped to each node on the map, according to your grid.